# Confused about taylor series first term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I ama trying to find the MacLaurin series of $xe^{-x}$ and since I know that

$$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

so $e^{-x} = $

$$e^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$

so $xe^{-x} = $

$$xe^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n!}$$

So I know this:

[image]

But when $n = 0$, the right side is = x but the f(x) is equal to 0? What is f(a) here? I'm trying to determine $T_0$ and $T_1$ and I think I'm a bit connfused here.

When figure out $T_0$, I just have to plug n = 0 into the equation I got right?

Comment: $a=0$ here.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, $T_0$ would be zero. This is because $xe^x$ evaluated at $0$ is $0$.

You'll need more terms in the series before it becomes a good approximation.

Comment: So I can't just olug in 0 into the sigma equation to find t0?

Comment: Let $f(x) = xe^x $,
$a = 0$,
$T_0 = 0*e^0$


,$f'(x) = (xe^x)' = e^x+xe^x$


, $T_1(x) = (x-0)f'(0) = x$

Comment: Oh wait 0^1 is 0 right? Is 0^0 = 0 as well?

Comment: Usually $0^0 = 1$, but I can't see how we use it here!

Comment: I am trying to find t0 so n would equal 0 right?

Comment: I am trying to show myself that the left and right side are equal when n= 0 for t0

Comment: $x e^x$ at $x=0$ is $0$.The other terms will all have $x^n$ in them so will also evaluate to $0$.